# Manage Device Orientation - IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, orientation

I'm really new to IOS develop and before ask this question I already tried literally all the answer on stackoverflow but couldn't find anything that work (probably I fail somewhere).

I want to **Disable the possibility of rotate the device** view in all my App **and I want to decide in every ControllerView if use portrait or landscape.**

How can I do that with Swift?

Answer (score 0):

you should try this on every ViewController an set it with the possibility to rotate, and what orientation should support.

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
}
```

I got this error:  [image: error]

Comment: I just paste it on my controller.swift but got this error on both functions: "Method does not override any method from its superclass"

Comment: Another error, added the screenshot error of both case

Comment: My bad. @Mago has Swift 2.x syntax. I'll post the Swift 3 syntax.

Comment: Yes Its swift 2.x Syntax!